# How to remove item from Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have container, which have `box`,`textfield` and `button`.  I am adding that container in one panel. When I am clicking on `button` I want to remove that container. Problem is, Container is removed but it not showing on UI.

My Code where I am removing container from panel.

```
 var panel = Ext.getCmp("ABC");
 var record = panel.items.items;
 var recordlength = record.length;

 for (var j = 0; j < recordlength - 1; j++) {
    if (record[j].Label == me.Label) {
      record.remove(me);
      panel.remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say you are able to remove container then try this to update your panel.

```
panel.update();
panel.doLayout();
```

It will update your panel after removing item from that.

Answer (score 2):

it works for me:

```
while (this.items.items[0]) {
  this.remove(this.items.items[0]);
}
```