# ExtJS 6.2: Clear the panel content before loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I'm using Ext Js v6.2 Grid, In my application,i'm trying to load some content to an existing panel with **component.load({url:''});** but the panel has already some content, how do i clear the panel content? I've searched in documentation and other stuff it doesn't help.please solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

It's not working.

```
panel.removeAll(true);
```

Panel Declaration:

```
var General = {
            items: [{
                    responsiveConfig: {
                        'width <= 1024': {
                            layout: {
                                type: 'box',
                                vertical: true,
                                align: 'stretch'
                            }
                        },
                        'width >= 1024': {
                            layout: {
                                type: 'box',
                                align: 'stretch',
                                vertical: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    anchor: '0',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    width: '100%',
                    title: data.GeneralImportHdr.importerNameJobInv,
                    border: false,
                    cls: 'CustomerPanel'
 }
```

Comment: can you provide more code (like panel declaration..)?

Comment: @Edwin code updated.

Comment: that's not enough and it's not even correct

Comment: try reading this post, seems you need to update your panel after removeAll https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715954/how-to-remove-item-from-panel

Comment: @bullettrain already tried that 'panel.update(); panel.doLayout();' both has been deprecated in Ver6.2.

Comment: Your question and the code given is a bit ambiguous. You have a Ext.gird.Panel or Ext.panel.Panel ? For panel.Panel --> panel.removeAll() followed by panel.add({ xtype :'container' , items:[]}) would work in Ext v6.